# Error al conectar mysql en Xamp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Tengo instalado el Xampp en Windows 10 desde hace muchos meses sin problemas, pero de repente al intentar conectar me ha negado la conexión a mysql. Lo raro es que una hora antes me había conectado sin errores y sin haber instalado ni cambiado nada una hora después no me dejaba. He cambiaado el puerto en my.ini y nada. También he borrado los archivos ib y aria de data y nada. He cerrado el antivirus y firewalls y nada. Estos son los textos de error que tengo:

En la interfaz:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:02:04  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:02:04  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:02:04  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:02:04  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:02:04  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:02:04  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

En el archivo de error:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-09 11:02:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 114115; transaction id 9
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200309 11:02:02
2020-03-09 11:02:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

la última opción sería reinstalar el Xampp, pero no sé como podría hacer un respaldo de las bases de datos sin entrar en mysql.

¿ Alguien me podría ayudar?

He instalado las bases de datos y archivos en otro portatil on Xampp que funcionaba perfectamente y parece ser que las bases de dato están corrompidas. Abro otra pregunta para poner el mensaje de error que ahora envía.

```
    2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1835037 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 188238788 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-03-09 20:02:37 16072 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace festivalito/jrw08xpn5_commentmeta uses space ID: 249 at filepath: .\festivalito\jrw08xpn5_commentmeta.ibd. Cannot open tablespace topografo/wp_options which uses space ID: 249 at filepath: .\topografo\wp_options.ibd
2020-03-09 20:02:37 3ec8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\topografo\wp_options.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
200309 20:02:37 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugsWe will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787129 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!?str_result@Item@@UAEPAVString@@PAV2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-03-09 20:09:20 4138 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2020-03-09 20:09:20 16696 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste alguna actualización de algo? ¿Reiniciaste el equipo? ¿Estás seguro de que no tienes un virus? ¿Estás seguro de que ningún menor estuvo trasteando en tu equipo? ¿No anduvo por ahí el gato cuando dejaste la base de datos abierta? etc...

Comment: Seguro del todo. Reinicié, apagué y nadie tocó el portatil. Una hora antes funcionaba todo correctamente y despues de apagar y volver a encender ya no me dejaba conectar

Comment: A veces el error ocurre por haber instalado algún programa nuevo que pasa a ocupar el puerto que antes estaba usando `mysql`. Por ejemplo en algunos casos la instalación de Skype u otros programas ha provocado ese fallo. Verifica qué puertos usa MySQL y XAMPP y revisa en la línea de comandos qué otras aplicaciones pueden estar usando esos puertos. Si mal no recuerdo el comando para eso era `netstat`

Comment: Comprobados los puertos. No hay otro programa ocupando ese puerto

Comment: En ese caso podrías tratar de entrar a MySQL desde la consola para hacer una copia de las bases de datos antes de reinstalar.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si. Creo que no me otra.

Comment: He instalado las bases de datos y archivos en otro portatil on Xampp que funcionaba perfectamente y parece ser que las bases de dato están corrompidas. Abro otra pregunta para poner el mensaje de error que ahora envía.

Comment: Puedes editar esta misma si quieres, porque es el mismo problema prácticamente. Agrega al final el nuevo mensaje de error. Es mejor tener todo en este contexto, creo yo. Puedes pulsar en [edit]  para modificar la pregunta.

Comment: Ya está . He colocado el código en el cuerpo del mensaje

Comment: OK, en primer lugar deberías verificar lo que se indica en estos tres puntos: `1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot  open the file, you should modify the permissions.  2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,  then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal  crash recovery and ignore that table.  3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove  the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf  and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.` O sea, 1º permisos, 2º echar mano de tu backup

Comment: Asegurate de no estar usando un software que use el puerto 3306 , tal como el Skype de microsoft., muchas veces el problema es que estos programas usan ese puerto para prestar servicios en redes P2p o de streaming y ya el MySql cuando inicia encuentra ese puerto ocupado.

Answer (score 0):

**OJO** Tener una salva de la base de datos.

Eliminé los archivos contenidos en `\xampp\mysql\data` y copié los datos contenidos en `\xampp\mysql\backup`. Luego importé mi db guardada.